# How to make a custom table widget in flutter?

Tags: layout, flutter, scrollview

I'm making a custom widget for showing a weekly schedule. I want it to look somewhat like a normal table, with the days in the header and the time of day on the vertical axis. Then I want to add events in the calendar, but as an event can span several cells, I can not use the built in table (it has no col/row span).

So I started to make my own table using CustomPaint. It went OK until I came to the header part, which I am stuck on the layout with my idea. In the code I supplied you can see that the header will have the same width as the side bar (with time) and the WeekView (the CustomPaint table). This means I have no idea how to align the header (Monday, Tuesday etc..) with the grid in the WeekView as the space the side bar takes up is not known. And as I want the side bar to scroll with the table, it has to be inside the scrollview. Can I solve this any other way? Maybe with slivers (that I know very little of yet)?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        WeekSelector(
          week: controller.week,
          onPrevPressed: onPrevPressed,
          onNextPressed: onNextPressed,
        ),
        WeekHeader(),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("09:00"), // here will be a bar for the time
                  Expanded(
                    child: WeekView(
                      startHour: 9,
                      endHour: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```